# Better way to find all iframes on the page

Tags: javascript

I am developing iPad application in that more than 6 iframes are available. After fully loaded the page, the page scroll went to the some where in the middle. So I decided to get page scrolltop written JavaScript code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        try {
            var iframecompleted = [];
            $("iframe[id*='iframe']").each(function(eli, el) {
                $(this).bind("load", iframeinit);
            });
            function iframeinit() {
                iframecompleted.push($(this).id);
                $(this).unbind("load", iframeinit);
            }

            var timer = setInterval(function() {
                if ($("iframe[id*='iframe']").length == iframecompleted.length) {
                    clearInterval(timer);
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: 0
                    }, 500);
                    if (FrameID != "") {
                        var j = 0;
                        var ss = FrameID.split(",")
                        for (j = 0; j < ss.length; j++) {
                            var collPanel = $find("pane" + ss[j]);
                            if (collPanel != null)
                                collPanel.set_Collapsed(true);
                        }
                        FrameID = "";
                    }
                }
            }, 10);
        }
        catch (e) {
            alert(e);
        }
    });
}
```

I would like to find a better way to achieve this task. Your ideas are more welcome.

Comment: What's `FrameID`? Also, your code can be easily optimized: If you only use `iframecompleted` for counting, don't use an array - use a number. Your iframe selector can be cached, and why are you calling `animate` on both `$('html, body')` and not just `$(body)`?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this :

```
var count = 0;

$("iframe").load(function() {
    if (++count === 6)
    {
        alert("TODO: All the frames are loaded, do you stuff");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eDVEY/

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var count = $('iframe').length;
    $(function() {
      $('iframe').load(function() {
        count--;
        if (count == 0)
            alert('all frames loaded');
      });
    });
```

Hope it helps

Comment: thank you.you are code look very simple.sure i use in my project.